# Cassandra - Ignore a Primary Key UUID on Where clausure

Tags: database, cassandra, datastax

In Cassandra Database how to ignore determined UUID values?

Like this:

```
select * from fenix where id != 8e6e41df-7701-4cfa-b037-63293e69215f
```

Exception:

> Unsupported "!=" relation: id != 8e6e41df-7701-4cfa-b037-63293e69215f

From [DataStax documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlSelect.html)

> "Restriction: a relation that references the partition key can only use an equality operator — = or IN. For more details about the IN operator, see Examples below."

How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

This is simply not possible in cassandra as it would require to scan through all records

Comment: YES! But how can we ignore any record in the query?

Comment: Filter out on the application side

Comment: Okay! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

It's possible with Solr:

`select * from fenix where solr_query = '-id:8e6e41df-7701-4cfa-b037-63293e69215f';` :)

More info on "Negative queries" section of [this link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/cql/cql/cql_using/search_index/tupleUDTqueryExamples.html).